# How do I force a figure on top of a line, and place it exactly where I want on the page?

Tags: floats, memoir

Background info is as such: Image A is a logo in the top right corner, around which I will write my name, and image B is of my average appearance, I want to place somewhere(!) on the left of my name and the logo. I think I want it to overlap the vertical rule that separates the top from the text. I have made it so there is an empty top line in the left side column to accommodate the placement of image B. The moving down of image B is done with the `vspace` command on line 32, however this command also moves the name and logo up.

In short, I would like two things; 
1) be able to have image B on top of the vertical line
2) be able to move the figures independently of the text, without them interfering with it. Complete freedom.

I have looked at all kinds of different packages; `wrapfigure`, `minipage`, `eso-pic`, `tikz`, but being an amateur I just made everything worse when I tried to use them.

Here's the minimal example.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn,oneside,final]{memoir}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage[marginparwidth=2cm,textwidth=18cm,textheight=27cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
    \usepackage[danish]{babel}
    \usepackage[danish]{isodate}
    \usepackage{floatflt}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{eso-pic}
    \usepackage{anyfontsize}
    \setlength\columnseprule{.4pt}

    \newcommand{\namesection}[3]{
        \flushright{\sffamily\fontsize{50}{80}\selectfont #1} \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a} \\
        {\fontsize{50}{80}\selectfont #2}  \\
        \vspace{5pt}
        {\fontsize{11}{14}\selectfont #3}
    }

    \begin{document}

    \pagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}[t!]
\hspace*{1cm}\includegraphics[height=5cm, width=4cm]{example-image-b}
\end{figure}

\vspace*{-8cm}

\namesection{First name}{Last Name}{\footnotesize Information about all sorts of neat stuff \hspace*{1.5cm}}

    \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{1.2\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}
    \vspace{-15pt}

    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \hfill \break
    \flushleft\lipsum
    \lipsum
    \end{multicols}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: `be able to have image B on top of the vertical line` you mean horizontal rule separet head from text or vertical rule separet columns?

Comment: And do you want this to appear on *every* page of your document? I mean, if you're going to have chapters, for example, should it also appear on the firat page of chapters (those pages normally have a different page style).

Comment: touhami: Yes the vertical rule.
Gonzalo: No, I want it on the first page, and only that one. The rest should just be two-colomn pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want complete freedom to move your elements, I'd suggest you to place them inside TikZ `\nodes`. In the exmaple below I first placed the node with the name and the information and then located the other two elements (the images) with respect to this node, but, of course, you are now free to select what goes first and where each element should appear. I used the tikzpagenodes package to have access to the `current page text area` family of nodes to locate the images (but this is optional).

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn,oneside,final]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=2cm,textwidth=18cm,textheight=27cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\setlength\columnseprule{.4pt}

\newcommand{\namesection}[3]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[text width=0.45\textwidth,inner sep=0pt]
  at ([yshift=-3.5cm]current page.north)
  (information)
  {\raggedright
    {\sffamily\fontsize{50}{80}\selectfont #1}\par
    {\fontsize{50}{80}\selectfont #2}\par
    {\fontsize{11}{14}\selectfont\footnotesize #3}%
  };
\node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=west]
  at (current page text area.west|-information.west)
  (imageb)
  {\includegraphics[height=5cm, width=4cm]{example-image-b}};
\node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=south east]
  at (current page text area.east|-information.south east)
  (imagea)
  {\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}};
\draw[line width=1pt]
  (current page.west|-imageb.south) -- (current page.east|-imageb.south);  
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\namesection{First name}{Last Name}{Information about all sorts of neat stuff}

\vspace{5cm}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\raggedright
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```